# Nesting a (vertical) UIPageViewController inside another (horizontal) UIPageViewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, nested

I have a big problem with my `UIPageViewController`. I want to present content in my app using sections and sub-sections. So, I have created **"two"** instances of `UIPageViewController` - horizontal (red) and vertical (blue):

[image: scheme]

Earlier I said I have created "two" instances - it is not quite true - there can be tens of instances, but only 2 are presented at the same time, **you know what I mean**. Both controllers have `transitionStyle` set to `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`.

The red `UIPageViewController` is responsible for horizontal scrolling between sections and blue are responsible for vertical scrolling.

They both work when separated but when I put vertical `UIPageViewController` in horizontal, **the vertical one stops working**.

My code is presented below:

---

**Horizontal `UIPageViewController` creation**

```
self.mainPageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:@{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]}];
self.mainPageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.mainPageViewController.delegate = self;

self.pdfDocsURLs = @[ @{@"v":[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1v" ofType:@"pdf"]],
                        @"h":[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1h" ofType:@"pdf"]]},

                      @{@"v":[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2v" ofType:@"pdf"]],
                        @"h":[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2h" ofType:@"pdf"]]},

                      @{@"v":[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3v" ofType:@"pdf"]],
                        @"h":[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3h" ofType:@"pdf"]]}];

UIIndexedPageViewController *pvc = [[UIIndexedPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical options:@{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]}];
pvc.index = 1;
PDFDocument *vdoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithPDFFileURL:self.pdfDocsURLs[0][@"v"] password:nil];
PDFDocument *hdoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithPDFFileURL:self.pdfDocsURLs[0][@"h"] password:nil];
PDFSinglePageViewController *svc = [[PDFSinglePageViewController alloc] initWithVerticalPDF:vdoc horizontalPDF:hdoc page:1];
[pvc setViewControllers:@[svc] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self.mainPageViewController setViewControllers:@[pvc] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Just to be clear, `UIIndexedPageViewController` is a subclass of UIPVC with extra `NSUInteger index` property. Its implementation is empty - it doesn't overwrite any methods.

---

**`UIPageViewController` dataSource methods**

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if(pageViewController == self.mainPageViewController) { // if horizontal
        UIIndexedPageViewController *ivc = (UIIndexedPageViewController *)viewController;
        if(ivc.index == self.pdfDocsURLs.count) return nil;
        UIIndexedPageViewController *pvc = [[UIIndexedPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical options:@{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]}];
        pvc.index = ivc.index+1;
        PDFDocument *vdoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithPDFFileURL:self.pdfDocsURLs[ivc.index][@"v"] password:nil];
        PDFDocument *hdoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithPDFFileURL:self.pdfDocsURLs[ivc.index][@"h"] password:nil];
        PDFSinglePageViewController *svc = [[PDFSinglePageViewController alloc] initWithVerticalPDF:vdoc horizontalPDF:hdoc page:1];
        [pvc setViewControllers:@[svc] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
        return pvc;
    } else { // if vertical - THE CODE BELOW IS NEVER EXECUTED
        PDFSinglePageViewController *ovc = (PDFSinglePageViewController *)viewController;
        NSUInteger nop = 0;
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(ovc.interfaceOrientation)) nop = ovc.verticalDoc.numberOfPages;
        else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(ovc.interfaceOrientation)) nop = ovc.horizontalDoc.numberOfPages;
        if(ovc.page == nop) return nil;
        PDFSinglePageViewController *svc = [[PDFSinglePageViewController alloc] initWithVerticalPDF:ovc.verticalDoc horizontalPDF:ovc.horizontalDoc page:ovc.page+1];
        return svc;
    }
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if(pageViewController == self.mainPageViewController) { // if horizontal
        UIIndexedPageViewController *ivc = (UIIndexedPageViewController *)viewController;
        if(ivc.index == 1) return nil;
        UIIndexedPageViewController *pvc = [[UIIndexedPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical options:@{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]}];
        pvc.index = ivc.index-1;
        PDFDocument *vdoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithPDFFileURL:self.pdfDocsURLs[ivc.index-2][@"v"] password:nil];
        PDFDocument *hdoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithPDFFileURL:self.pdfDocsURLs[ivc.index-2][@"h"] password:nil];
        PDFSinglePageViewController *svc = [[PDFSinglePageViewController alloc] initWithVerticalPDF:vdoc horizontalPDF:hdoc page:1];
        [pvc setViewControllers:@[svc] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
        return pvc;
    } else { // is vertical - THE CODE BELOW IS NEVER EXECUTED
        PDFSinglePageViewController *ovc = (PDFSinglePageViewController *)viewController;
        NSUInteger nop = 0;
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(ovc.interfaceOrientation)) nop = ovc.verticalDoc.numberOfPages;
        else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(ovc.interfaceOrientation)) nop = ovc.horizontalDoc.numberOfPages;
        if(ovc.page == 1) return nil;
        PDFSinglePageViewController *svc = [[PDFSinglePageViewController alloc] initWithVerticalPDF:ovc.verticalDoc horizontalPDF:ovc.horizontalDoc page:ovc.page-1];
        return svc;
    }
}
```

---

So it seems that horizontal `UIPageViewController` doesn't allow the vertical one to even receive pan gesture recognizers.

---

**My question is...** Is there a way to allow the vertical `UIPageViewController` to receive touches and scroll in both directions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the direction in your useful question. doing something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to assign `dataSource` and `delegate` properties of my vertical page view controllers in

- `-pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:`
- `-pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:`

Problem solved, everything works beautifully.