# Can I embed a UIPageViewController in a UIPageViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController`, which obviously I can set to horizontal or vertical scrolling.

My question is can I embed a `UIPageViewController` inside another `UIPageViewController`, and set one to `vertical` and one to `horizontal`, so that I have `vertical` scrolling through some categories, and then `horizontal` scrolling for objects in the categories?

If not, is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend to review the possibility to use UICollectionView instead. And the use section tiles to describes categories and cells in those sections to display items in the category.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any examples of this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use nested UIPageViewController & both work fine and independently.[look this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039792/nesting-a-vertical-uipageviewcontroller-inside-another-horizontal-uipageview)